Orbits of the action of the Chevalley group of type $B_n$ in characteristic 2.
I would like to learn more about the orbits of the action of the Chevalley group of type $B_n$, with $n$ even, on it's representation of highest weight $\omega_n$, which is isomorphic to the Clifford algebra, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 2.
Can someone give me some references which can help me to find the orbits.
